# LHS of always block in verilog need to be reg, but index of array in LHS of always block cannot be a reg, is it true?

Tags: verilog, synthesis

I am trying to synthesize a verilog file with some part of code like this(obviously i hadn't declared module and other input and output variables)

```
input [15:0] me;

reg [15:0] p_array [7:0];
reg abc_pqr [2:0];

abc_pqr[0] <= me[0];
abc_pqr[1] <= me[1];
abc_pqr[2] <= me[1];
p_array[abc_pqr[0]] <= me[0];
p_array[abc_pqr[1]] <= me[1];
p_array[abc_pqr[2]] <= me[2];
```

where i had used reg as index of array element, so is it not valid, though this module inside my verilog file didn't synthesized as it contain a memory element but just want to confirm that is it valid to use reg as array index?
I dint find anything on net in this regards,but taking reg as index will make array act as buffer and i think it must be a valid code.

Comment: There are several problems with this code, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @trav1s: It just a part of module in a code.yes i had't declared input and module but it was the part of code regarding which i am concern and my main question is that can we have reg as index value of array in LHS of always block?

Comment: You have multiple non-blocking statements, for one, which is a major problem. I suggest you pick up a linting tool as it will tell you what about your code is bad, ugly, or unsynthesizeable: http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/tools.html Also, I recommend this reference since you have so many questions about Verilog http://www.sutherland-hdl.com/online_verilog_ref_guide/verilog_2001_ref_guide.pdf

Comment: In particular, the sections, "Vector Bit Selects and Part Selects" and "Synthesis Supported Constructs" will answer your question thoroughly.

Answer (score 4):

A `reg` can be used as the index value of array in LHS of always block.

A `reg` is a value that can store a value. It does not *need* continuous assignment like a `wire`. `reg` is not synonymous with flop (or latch) and this where some get confused. Flops and latches are decided by the synthesizer based on RTL coding style. Examples:

```
reg [15:0] a, b, c, q, idx;
always @(posedge clk) a <= q; // 'a' will be a flop
always @* if(en) b <= a; // 'b' will be a latch
always @* c = a ^ b; // 'c' will be wire (continuous assignment)
always @(posedge clk)
  for(idx=0; idx<16; idx=idx+1) // 'idx' will be omitted in synthesis
    q[idx] <= idx%2 ? a[idx]^c[15-idx] : a[15-idx]^c[idx]; // 'q' will be a flop
    // synthesis will create an intermediate wire(s) for the D pin to the 'q' flop
```

`reg`s do need to be assigned inside an `always` block to synthesized. For behavior modeling `reg` can also be in assigned in any `initial` blocks, `task`, and `function`.

Comment: A reg used as the bit or part select on the left-hand side of an assignment is NOT a supported synthesis construct. "A reg is a value that can store a value" is not helpful. The rest of the information in the answer irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @trav1s left-hand bit or part select is supported by at least some synthesizers. I'm still looking for reference to learn if this is IEEE Std 1364-2005, IEEE Std 1800, or a feature that some vendors added. Sutherland's reference guide is a great source, however it is 2001 and both the Verilog standard and synthesis tools have been updated/improved.